# How to render text to output without waiting for function to finish?

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

I am new to Shiny coding, and I am writing code to implement image processing and calculation. However, I am having a problem as the output text is displayed only when the function has finish executed.

The following is the part of code I have:

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    for(i in 1:100){
        processImage(i);
        output$console <- renderText({
            paste(i," images completed");
        })
    }

    processImage(i) <- function (){
        # code goes here
    }
}
```

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel(
        h4("Image Processing")
    ),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            # some inputs here
        ),
        mainPanel(
            textOutput('console')
        )
    )
))
```

`output$console` is not rendered until the for loop is finished. I have search the Internet for the solution, but found none. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Not sure about Shiny code but in regular are there is a `flush.console` function.

Comment: As the `output$console` is not the same as the console, so the flush.console is not working for me. Tried every possible way that I am aware of, but still no clue on how to render text while the function is still running.

Comment: Is this helpful? http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/onflush-example.html

Comment: @BondedDust the example is not using a loop, so it is actually not the sample as this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this with `withProgress`. **Edit:** You need to install `shinyIncubator` package

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinyIncubator)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    if(input$aButton==0) return(NULL)
    withProgress(session, min=1, max=15, expr={
      for(i in 1:10) {
        setProgress(message = 'Processing...',detail = paste0('Image number ',i))
        Sys.sleep(0.5)
      }
    })
  })
}

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Testing"),
  sidebarPanel(actionButton("aButton", "Let's go!"), width=2),

  mainPanel(progressInit())
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: I get an error: `ERROR: could not find function "progressInit"`

Comment: Need to install `shinyIncubator` package, sorry!

Comment: thanks, aside from rendering the progress outside the `output$console` using progressbar, can the progress be rendered with `output$console`? As what I want is to display the progress in the mainPanel.

Comment: yeah, do you have any solution to my problem above?